# Shift + numeric keypad prints number (with NumLock off)

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, lenovo, keyboard-layout

Since Lenovo have decided to place the `Home` and `End` keys in unreachable locations on my Thinkpad, I use the numeric keypad for these. With `NumLock` off, `1` = `End` and `7` = `Home`. One typical use for this is to select text from the current cursor position to the end of the line (`Shift` + (numpad) `1`).

This used to work fine until very recently, after I installed updates and rebooted. Now `Shift` + (numpad) `1` just prints the character "1".

I found an option in the system settings: *Keyboard > Advanced > Miscellaneous compatibility options > Shift with numeric keypad keys works as in MS Windows*. This option fixes the problem (restores the way it worked before), but also changes my `H` key to type "W", which is quite inconvenient, as you can imagine. All other keys work like before.

This only occurs with the German keyboard layout, not the default US layout.

What to do?

System: Lenovo Thinkpad W550S, Kubuntu 15.10

Comment: This seems more like a bug and is not something intended. Does anyone still facing such issue?